# Why is Android not using the most recent gradle version?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried using gradle 5.5.1 as the gradle version of my project but after successful downloading, it, unfortunately, failed to synchronize. Anyone with the idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Android not using the most recent gradle version?

In general there is a [compatibility](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) between the gradle version and the Android Gradle plugin.

> The following table lists which version of Gradle is required for each version of the Android Gradle plugin. For the best performance, you should use the latest possible version of both Gradle and the plugin.

```
Plugin version  Required Gradle version
1.0.0 - 1.1.3   2.2.1 - 2.3
1.2.0 - 1.3.1   2.2.1 - 2.9
1.5.0           2.2.1 - 2.13
2.0.0 - 2.1.2   2.10 - 2.13
2.1.3 - 2.2.3   2.14.1+
2.3.0+          3.3+
3.0.0+          4.1+
3.1.0+          4.4+
3.2.0 - 3.2.1   4.6+
3.3.0 - 3.3.2   4.10.1+
3.4.0+          5.1.1+
```

In your case gradle 5.5.1 should work with the android plugin 3.4.2.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after changing the plugin to 3.4.2